# How to preserve App Keys of an Azure Function after swapping slots?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have this resource in azure.

- (fa-001) Function App (**Resource A**)
- (fa-001/slot) App Service (Slot) (**Resource B**)

Both resource have the url's below.

- https://fa-001.azurewebsites.net/api/Example_Function (**Resource A**)
- https://fa-001-slot.azurewebsites.net/api/Example_Function (**Resource B**)

When running locally I need to use the default App Keys in order to access the functions.

So the url's looks like below.

- https://fa-001.azurewebsites.net/api/Example_Function?code=XXX (**Resource A**)
- https://fa-001-slot.azurewebsites.net/api/Example_Function?code=YYY (**Resource B**)

I executed the url's initially on POSTMAN without a problem.
Now, I have a yaml script in azure devops that will swap the slots of this resources.
I executed the yaml script.

**Resource A** will become **Resource B**.
**Resource B** will become **Resource A**.

I executed the urls again on POSTMAN but with a 401 response.

- https://fa-001.azurewebsites.net/api/Example_Function?code=XXX (**Resource A**)
- https://fa-001-slot.azurewebsites.net/api/Example_Function?code=YYY (**Resource B**)

But If I swap the codes, I can access the url's without any problem.

- https://fa-001.azurewebsites.net/api/Example_Function?code=YYY (**Resource A**)
- https://fa-001-slot.azurewebsites.net/api/Example_Function?code=XXX (**Resource B**)

Is there a way to preserve App Keys when swapping azure function slots ?
If there's a way, how ?

Answer (score 1):

***Please check the below workaround I have done:***

- Created Azure Functions .NET 6 App in the Portal with 2 deployment slots: Production and Staging.

Production Slot - ProdHttpTrigger
Staging Slot - StagingHttpTrigger

***These are the App Keys different in those 2 slots:***

[image]

***After Swapping:***

**Functions** changed in between the slots but not the **App Keys** (Code=Value).

***Every time you swap, the keys will not change and both slots use the same keys***.

Those keys will be reset during swapping the slots and having the app setting `AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType` to `files`.

You can also use Function Keys where you create the custom key-value pair of that API/trigger and that works for both the slots as similar to the App Keys.